# How can I make my navigation appear on a certain section of my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make it disappear on `#part1` section then make the navigation bar appear on section `#part2,3,4`?

I tried changing the value from 301 to 0 but the nav bar was still there.
On `#part1` I don’t want the navigation bar to be visible. However, on section 2,3,4 which is known as `#part2, #part3, and #part4` I want the navigation to appear.

Here is an [example](http://findmatthew.com) of the concept that I'm trying to get my portfolio to look like in terms of the navigation bar.

[Site code](https://jsfiddle.net/vx85qub9/7/)

```
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 0) {
    $(".navbar").show();
  } else {
    $(".navbar").slideUp(400);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `var windowHeight = $(window).height();` before the function and change `< 0` into `> windowHeight`

So it will show when you've scrolled down for 100vh

Also add a display: none property to .navbar

So it will hide the navbar initially.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post do you have a working jsfiddle?